# Crossfiltering with heatmap dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Trying to build a [simple dashboard](https://codepen.io/shakraz/pen/dyYXxJy) with heatmap (build as a cartogram) and rowchart. Selecting region, i expect to see changes on rowchart and vice versa. But it doesn't work in this way.

```
var dim = ndx.dimension(d=>[d.x,d.y,d.region])

var group = dim.group().reduce(
    (p,v)=>{
        ++p.count;
        p.total+=v.salary;
        p.avg_salary=p.total/p.count;
return p
},
(p,v)=>{
    --p.count;
    p.total-=v.salary;
    p.avg_salary=p.total/v.count;
return p
},
()=>({avg_salary: 0,count: 0,total:0})
)


var graduationDim = ndx.dimension(d=>d.graduation)
var graduationGroup = graduationDim.group().reduce(
        (p,v)=>{
        ++p.count;
        p.total+=v.salary;
        p.avg_salary=p.total/p.count;
return p
},
(p,v)=>{
    --p.count;
    p.total-=v.salary;
    p.avg_salary=p.total/v.count;
return p
},
()=>({avg_salary: 0,count: 0,total:0}))
```

What am i doing wrong? Any help or advice is highly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in your reduce-remove functions, `v.count` should be `p.count`:

```
(p,v)=>{
    --p.count;
    p.total-=v.salary;
    p.avg_salary=p.total/p.count;
return p
},
```

Since this field doesn't exist in your original data, you are probably getting NaNs.

[Working fork of your codepen](https://codepen.io/gordonwoodhull/pen/eYpxWea).